# How to assign value to a date in an xts object in R

Tags: r, xts

I assumed the following code

```
date = as.Date('2015-05-30')
timeseries = xts()
timeseries[date] = 1
```

should assign the value of 1 to a date '2015-05-30'. However, it gives me an error

```
Error in xts(rep(NA, length(index(x))), index(x)) : 
  order.by requires an appropriate time-based object
```

What is the proper way to assign the value to an empty xts object?

Thanks,
Vladimir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the purpose of the `[<-.xts` function. You're asking to replace the value at date `"2015-05-30"` with `1`, but your xts object has no data, so there's nothing to replace. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

If you want to insert, you should call `rbind(xts(1, as.Date('2015-05-30')), timeseries)`.

---

And you should heed [Mike Wise's wise advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549926/how-to-assign-value-to-a-date-in-an-xts-object-in-r#comment49172371_30550102): it is very inefficient to grow objects like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
d1 <- rep(1,21)
d2 <- seq(as.Date("2001-01-01",tz="GMT"),as.Date("2021-01-01",tz="GMT"),length.out=21)
xtsdat <- as.xts(d1,d2)
```

If you need to build it up row by row, then build the individual vectors that way and form the xts at the end.

Comment: I know this is going to work but I was asking a different question. I thought vectorlike syntax should work for xts.

Comment: `timeSeries = vector()`
`timeSeries[1] = 1`

Comment: Maybe it does, but it is rather "un-R-like" to do it that way. R gets very slow if it has to reallocate all the time. There is a good discussion of this in Hadley's "Advanced R" book.